# Disable refresh browser in only one page using angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to ask if it's possible to disable the refresh of the browser in one page only using angular or javascript.

Comment: u mean bowser hardware button?

Comment: yes and also the f5 key.

Comment: you can prevent f5, but browser refresh is not possible through javascript.

Comment: @Raj, really? that makes me sad :-(. But thanks

Comment: Repeated question answer link. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25040472/2114046

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.onkeydown = function(){
  switch (event.keyCode){
        case 116 : //F5 button
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false;
        case 82 : //R button
            if (event.ctrlKey){ 
                event.returnValue = false;
                event.keyCode = 0;
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

This code helps you to prevent f5 and ctrl + R functionality

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we never could. And I believe we never should.

Comment: this is not a answer. it should be a comment.

Comment: I think Lee want to know not only the way to achieve but also the possibility to achieve. Therefore Answering 'Impossible' could be answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($){
   $('[data-toggle="redirect"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
   });
   $('.job-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

It will help you dude