# Angular JS detecting and preventing page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm trying to detect and prevent a page reload in angular.

I have seen this post:
[How to handle / prevent browser navigation or reload in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040252/how-to-handle-prevent-browser-navigation-or-reload-in-angularjs#)

but it's not working.  Even when event.preventDefault() is called, the page still reloads and a blank page is displayed after reload.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
I may be misunderstanding the problem.  The code I have is just like in the link posted above:

```
appRun.$inject = ['$window'];
function appRun($window) {
  var windowElem = angular.element($window);
  windowElem.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Can we see the code please?

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. The problem isnt' that the page is reloading, it's that the server is not responding with /index.html when you request /some/angular/route, instead it's trying to respond with /some/angular/route/index.html which doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer at the question you linked can't possibly work in modern browsers. Modern browsers don't let you stop that event other than returning a string and letting the user decide whether or not to stay.

Comment: kevin, can you suggest anything to prevent a reload?

Comment: No, because the browser doesn't give you control of that.

Comment: if that's the case, do you know how single page apps usually handle page refreshes?

Comment: @looseScrews are you asking like how do they store information if it is refreshed?

Comment: @looseScrews If you need to store information between refreshes, localstorage is the answer. SPA's usually handle page refreshes by having every page request result in /index.html being returned rather than /some/fake/path/index.html. This is handled server-side.

Comment: Harshal: I think storing information may be part of the problem.
When I navigate to a view that is nested and click refresh, the page gets reloaded with only the header of the page showing, everything else is white. Before entering this page, some information is resolved.  As far as i know, a refresh is literally restarting the app from scratch.  So i was wondering how to detect a refresh event (ctrl + r, ctrl + shift + f5, f5, etc..), then prevent it, and do a $state.reload() or something instead.

Comment: based on the extra information you added in your comments, you are *definitely* trying to solve the wrong problem.  You shouldn't be trying to prevent a reload, you should be handling correctly your data when a reload occurs.

Comment: Ok that's fine.  Just to add, when the blank page shows up, if i click the back button on the browser, the previous state is loaded completely, and i can go back into the reloaded state just fine.
For example, i have a breadcrumb directive.  When I reload the page, it loses all data and disappears.  When I click back, it reloads all data just fine.