# Can not prevent browser page refresh/reload in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my site with angularjs SPA. When user clicks on refresh button or press F5/ Ctrl + F5 to I want to prevent, or abort page reloading. Unfortunately, solution with `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events are not working. Actually, they are called, `event.preventDefault()` line is reached, there are any messages in console, but browser continue to load page.

My current module `.run()` code:

```
let window = angular.element($window);
window.on("beforeunload", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}).on("unload", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
});

// This is just for sure that I have my handlers registered 
$window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}

$window.onunload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

How can I really handle this in angular?

**UPDATE**

I need this for reloading actual state instead of page. So when user clicks refresh I want to just reload current state with `$stateProvider` and not to reload the whole page

Comment: Why do you want this? I can't think of any good reason for doing that

Comment: please see my update

Comment: I don't think it is possible and I don't think it should be. From a browser perspective, the refresh button should be outside of the scope of the document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out what [Mozilla has to say about unload events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload). It looks like it is not possible to prevent a refresh like you want to. The only think that you can do is to ask the user if he/she really wants to leave the page.

I guess you could reload the current state in the case the user answers that he/she does not want to leave the current page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    // do some stuff here, like reloading your current state
    //this would work only if the user chooses not to leave the page
    return 'why would you do that???';
}
```

I have created a [fiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/brunokrebs/Lda61q3d/12/).

Comment: And how can I handle what user said? I mean, how can I recognize is his answer "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: Well, like I wrote in the comments. If the user choose to leave your page everything in the scope of javascript will be lost, if the user choose not to leave, everything will be just like before. So you can just write you logic before the return statement.

Like that, if he chooses to stay, your logic will persist.

Comment: It works, thanks. But the only one problem is when I choose 'Reload' my logic is also tries to run, but browser reloading the page. Is it possible to skip this?

Comment: No, I don't see how to achieve that. There is no callback to a 'stay on page' answer where we could put code that should be run in case he opts to stay. Guess you just have to hope that the user opts to stay.

Comment: I guess too, I only can hope for that :)

Comment: This works fine, but how can i change alert box message?
It gives me message, "Changes that you have made may not be saved".

How can i update this message.
Thanks