# Navigating elm from URL without destroying state (elm 0.18)

Tags: elm

I have an elm app that incorporates logging in and fetching data from a server.  Once I've logged in, I navigate to `/#/pages/13` and it updates the model with page id 13.  If I click around within the app, I see evidence that that page persists in the model.

When I navigate away from that page via internal links, then enter `http://localhost:3000/#/pages/13` into the URL, I still see that page.

If I enter that URL *while I am at that location*, it seems to treat the behavior as a complete refresh, resetting the model...including my token, so it logs me out.

How can I enter the same page into the URL without elm resetting the model?

(If it matters, I am using gulp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour seems to be by design, although I didn't find an official source for this.

The most you can do is [register a `beforeunload` listener,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) which *might* show a prompt allowing the user to cancel the navigation.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34415095/2014893